# how can i express value like 256359 in pakistan currency

Tags: c#

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kUXOI.png)hi everyone i want to rewrite a value like 256359 in pakistan standard currency like Rs 2,56,359 in c# code.
here is my code

```
CultureInfo cultureInfos = new CultureInfo();   
val = string.Format("C",cultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ur-PK"));
```

Comment: So what is wrong with your code?

Comment: did't get the correct answer

Comment: Are you looking for something like `string stringValue = numericValue.ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ur-PK"));`?

Comment: @Corak Probably, the code sample in the question is kinda strange

Comment: Please post code as code and *not* as image. Please provide a so called [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) -- that said, in your example `val` is already a `string`. Using `ToString` on a `string` doesn't make sense. You can try `string val = (netAmount - xpayedAmoount).ToString("C", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("ur-PK"));`

Comment: the problem is that `val` is already a string. the number formatting overloads of the `ToString` function apply only numeric types (int, decimal, ...). solution: do not convert the result of your computation to a string. `val` must be a number type. would you mind adding the code as text and not as an image,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code sample does not even compile, and it does not include the number you want to convert.

Try this approach:

```
var val = 256359.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ur-PK"));
```

Result:

> Rs256,359.00

Comment: im getting error and not to execute this code... my expectation is just like that you have written like Rs213,434.00

Comment: compile time sir

Comment: then please include your code (everything needed to reproduce the problem, a mninimal complete example), and the error details in your original post. it is impossible to help without more detail.

Answer (score 0):

code should be like:

```
int val = (netAmount - xpayedAmoount); 
this.lblCreditAmount.Text = val.ToString("C", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("ur-PK"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I use custom written function:

```
//Input: "256359.2000" Output: "Rs 256,359.20"
//Input: "256359.20"   Output: "Rs 256,359.20"
//Input: "256359"      Output: "Rs 256,359.20"

public static string ConvertPKR(this string amount) 
{
    try 
    {
        decimal value = 0.00M;
        value = Convert.ToDecimal(amount);
        return "Rs " + String.Format("{0:n2}", value);
    } 
    catch (Exception ex) 
    {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```